# R - Measuring tree model performance with confusion matrix

Tags: r, cart

I have a data set that has 16 columns. 1-15 are the predictors and 16 is the response.

I build my tree model:

`tree_model <- tree(V16~.,
                    my_data)`

I see how well the model does on the original data set:

`prediction <- predict(tree_model,
               my_data,
               "vector") # Type of prediction`

Now the problem is that the response variable is not binary, rather a number. For specifics, column 16 is the estimated crime per x population.

When I try putting the items in a confusion matrix, it doesn't turn out quite right:

```
cfm <- table(my_data$V16, prediction)
cfm

+--------+-----------+-----+-----+-----+
|        | Predicted |     |     |     |
+--------+-----------+-----+-----+-----+
| Actual |       466 | 477 | 600 | 900 |
| 370    |         1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
| 390    |         1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
| 470    |         0 |   1 |   0 |   0 |
| 950    |         0 |   0 |   0 |   1 |
+--------+-----------+-----+-----+-----+
```

I think I understand why. I believe my next step is to choose an appropriate threshold or classify the item as being true or false? True being that the predicted value is "close enough" to the original, and false being that it is not within. If so, how do I choose a "right" threshold or classifying method?

Please advise is this is not the correct step.

Comment: Is there a reason that you want to use a confusion matrix? Confusion matrices are really for scenarios where the response is categorical.  Have you considered using another metric like MSE to assess your model's accuracy?